# NULL values in mysql table prevent records from being searchable

Tags: php, mysql

I am somewhat of a weekend warrior when it comes to php and mysql. I use Dreamweaver 8 to build my code for the most part, but do some hand coding in TextWrangler when necessary.

I have a table that has 28 columns and currently has 1224 rows (and is growing). I used DW8 to build the code for the Advanced Search Page. It works great, **except** that if a row has NULL in one or more of the columns (which a lot of them do) it will not retrieve that record. This is a problem. I need for it to ignore the NULL values and retrieve the record anyway.

I have found that if I modify all of the records in the table to have something other than NULL, like a space or a dash, the query will find the records. As new records are entered there will be new NULLs added to the table and those records will not be searchable.

These columns have to allow NULL because the Add Record page inserts into this table and also another table and they must be in sequence. I have found that if I set the columns to not accept NULL, one table accepts the data, and the other rejects the data, then the Primary Keys get off sync.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/mediadb.php'); ?>
<?php $currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>

if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rsResults'])) {
$pageNum_rsResults = $_GET['pageNum_rsResults'];
}
$startRow_rsResults = $pageNum_rsResults * $maxRows_rsResults;

$varkind_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchkind'])) {
  $varkind_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchkind'] : addslashes($_GET['searchkind']);
}
$varcomments_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchnotes'])) {
  $varcomments_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchnotes'] : addslashes($_GET['searchnotes']);
}
$varrating_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchrating'])) {
  $varrating_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchrating'] : addslashes($_GET['searchrating']);
}
$varloc_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchlocation'])) {
  $varloc_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchlocation'] : addslashes($_GET['searchlocation']);
}
$vardiscnum_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchdisc_number'])) {
  $vardiscnum_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchdisc_number'] : addslashes($_GET['searchdisc_number']);
}
$vardisccnt_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchdisc_count'])) {
  $vardisccnt_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchdisc_count'] : addslashes($_GET['searchdisc_count']);
}
$vartrackcnt_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchtrack_count'])) {
  $vartrackcnt_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchtrack_count'] : addslashes($_GET['searchtrack_count']);
}
$vartracknum_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchtrack_number'])) {
  $vartracknum_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchtrack_number'] : addslashes($_GET['searchtrack_number']);
}
$varyear_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchyear'])) {
  $varyear_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchyear'] : addslashes($_GET['searchyear']);
}
$varmod_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchmodified'])) {
  $varmod_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchmodified'] : addslashes($_GET['searchmodified']);
}
$varadd_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchdate_added'])) {
  $varadd_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchdate_added'] : addslashes($_GET['searchdate_added']);
}
$varrecnum_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchrecnum'])) {
  $varrecnum_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchrecnum'] : addslashes($_GET['searchrecnum']);
}
$vartime_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchtime'])) {
  $vartime_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchtime'] : addslashes($_GET['searchtime']);
}
$vargenre_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchgenre'])) {
  $vargenre_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchgenre'] : addslashes($_GET['searchgenre']);
}
$vargroup_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchgrouping'])) {
  $vargroup_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchgrouping'] : addslashes($_GET['searchgrouping']);
}
$varalbum_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchalbum'])) {
  $varalbum_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchalbum'] : addslashes($_GET['searchalbum']);
}
$varcomp_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchcomp'])) {
  $varcomp_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchcomp'] : addslashes($_GET['searchcomp']);
}
$varartist_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchartist'])) {
  $varartist_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchartist'] : addslashes($_GET['searchartist']);
}
$varname_rsResults = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['searchname'])) {
  $varname_rsResults = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['searchname'] : addslashes($_GET['searchname']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_mediadb, $mediadb);
$query_rsResults = sprintf("SELECT recnum, name, artist, composer, album, `grouping`, genre, `time`,  year, date_modified, date_added, kind, comments, my_rating, location, track_number, track_count, disc_number, disc_count 
FROM media_lib
WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%' AND artist LIKE '%%%s%%' AND composer LIKE '%%%s%%' AND album LIKE '%%%s%%' AND `grouping` LIKE '%%%s%%' AND genre LIKE '%%%s%%' AND `time` LIKE '%%%s%%' AND recnum LIKE '%%%s%%' AND date_added LIKE '%%%s%%' AND date_modified LIKE '%%%s%%' AND year LIKE '%%%s%%' AND track_number LIKE '%%%s%%' AND track_count LIKE '%%%s%%' AND disc_number LIKE '%%%s%%' AND disc_count LIKE '%%%s%%' AND kind LIKE '%%%s%%' AND comments LIKE '%%%s%%' AND my_rating LIKE '%%%s%%' AND location LIKE '%%%s%%'", $varname_rsResults,$varartist_rsResults,$varcomp_rsResults,$varalbum_rsResults,$vargroup_rsResults,$vargenre_rsResults,$vartime_rsResults,$varrecnum_rsResults,$varadd_rsResults,$varmod_rsResults,$varyear_rsResults,$vartracknum_rsResults,$vartrackcnt_rsResults,$vardiscnum_rsResults,$vardisccnt_rsResults,$varkind_rsResults,$varcomments_rsResults,$varrating_rsResults,$varloc_rsResults);
$query_limit_rsResults = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rsResults, $startRow_rsResults, $maxRows_rsResults);
$rsResults = mysql_query($query_limit_rsResults, $mediadb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsResults);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rsResults'])) {
  $totalRows_rsResults = $_GET['totalRows_rsResults'];
} else {
  $all_rsResults = mysql_query($query_rsResults);
  $totalRows_rsResults = mysql_num_rows($all_rsResults);
}
$totalPages_rsResults = ceil($totalRows_rsResults/$maxRows_rsResults)-1;

$queryString_rsResults = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_rsResults") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_rsResults") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_rsResults = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_rsResults = sprintf("&totalRows_rsResults=%d%s", $totalRows_rsResults, $queryString_rsResults);
?>
```

Comment: Obligatory "you should use prepared statements" comment. [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) are good.

Comment: Have you considered defining the columns as NOT NULL ?

Comment: I would also add that addslashes() might be best replaced by mysql_real_escape_string().  That is not as good as migrating to the more current SQL drivers, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: > Have you considered defining the columns as NOT NULL ?

Yes, as I mentioned though, under some circumstances this can cause the primary key in the two tables involved to get out of sync.

> I would also add that addslashes() might be best replaced by mysql_real_escape_string().

Based on your suggestion, I tried this, but saw no difference in the result. I even tried mysqli_real_escape_string(). There doesn't seem to be any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `ifnull` to convert `NULL`s to (say) empty strings in your `WHERE` clause.  For example, `name LIKE '%%%s%%'` would become `ifnull(name, '') LIKE '%%%s%%'`.

Like your current code, it assumes your various `$_GET` parameters are set - it won't match the `-1` you're using if the parameter isn't set.

Comment: I think you're better off using the empty string (eg `$varartist_rsResults = "";`).  As an example, if the URL doesn't contain the "searchname" parameter, the SQL generated will contain `WHERE name LIKE '%-1%'`, which probably isn't what you want - it'll limit the results, which wouldn't make sense to me.  If you use the empty string, it'll be `WHERE name LIKE '%%'`, which will match everything (assuming you also apply the `ifnull()` change).  It's the `ifnull()` change that should fix the problem you asked about.